# I am using the js-modern-calendar but is there a way to add eventsdirectly from the calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am working on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-modern-calendar .. but can we add the ability to go to specific day and add events?
Thanks

Comment: This SPFx sample uses FullCalendar library to show the calendar. Check [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174744/how-to-set-full-calendar-to-a-specific-start-date-when-its-initialized-for-the) for go to date and [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-model) for event model in FullCalendar.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the info, can you provide sample of the related code i need to add? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the exact code to share as this is additional functionality & need development efforts.